# Pandas shift columns halfway through DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1,2,2,3], [-1,3,4,5], [6,7,8,-1], [8,9,0,-1]])

        0   1   2   3

0       -1  2   2   3
1       -1  3   4   5
2       6   7   8   -1
3       8   9   0   -1
```

This dataset is misaligned. -1 indicates garbage values. I tried aligning the columns to get this:

```
        0   1   2   3

0       -1  2   2   3
1       -1  3   4   5
2       6   6   7   8
3       8   8   9   0
```

With the following code:

```
df.iloc[2:, 1:] = df.iloc[2:, :-1]
```

Then drop col 0 and be done, however, this doesn't work and produces instead:

```
        0     1     2     3

0       -1.0  2.0   2.0   3.0
1       -1.0  3.0   4.0   5.0
2       6.0   7.0   8.0   NaN
3       8.0   9.0   0.0   NaN
```

I could split it into two frames, change one and stitch them back together, but I feel like aligning the columns should be possible.

What is the fastest way to align the columns?

I'm not concerned with the int to float conversion.

Desired end result:

```
        1   2   3

0       2   2   3
1       3   4   5
2       6   7   8
3       8   9   0
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I fail what is the exact operation you want to do after seeing your example.

Comment: So you want to move all the '-1' to the column 0 and remove the column?

Comment: @AlejandroA that is correct. The dataset contains garbage in the first column for the first N rows, then the garbage is in the last column for the last M rows. I want to know if I can shift the final part such that it aligns with the first part, then drop the garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.iloc[2:, 1:] = df.iloc[2:, :-1].values
```

When you assign a dataframe to a slice of a dataframe, It will match columns by their names, sort of **like a dictionary**. Column 0 will edit column 0 etc... regardless of the positions of the left part of the assignment.
Note that your column names are 0, 1, 2 etc.

When you call `.values`, the left dataframe becomes a numpy ndarray of numbers with *no column names* so what you intended happens, sort of **like an array**.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work without using `.values`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
df.iloc[:,2:4] = df.iloc[:,2:4].replace(-1,float("nan")).ffill(axis = 1)
df = df.replace(-1,float("nan")).dropna(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3
0   2   2.0 3.0
1   3   4.0 5.0
2   7   8.0 8.0
3   9   0.0 0.0
```